# MICROSOFT SQL Server how do i update a column after a transfer is complete (homework)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

The homework question:

Write a stored procedure called `TransferRegion` that accepts a `RegionID` and a `DistributorID`.  The procedure will transfer a particular region from one distributor to another. When the region is transferred the old distributor will have $1.00 subtracted from their wage and the new distributor will have $1.00 added their wage. Ensure all necessary tables are updated as required.

My question: how do I update the old distributor wage after its been transferred out?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TransferRegion 
    (@RegionID INT = NULL, @DistributorID INT = NULL)
AS
    IF @RegionID IS NULL OR @DistributorID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        raiserror('Must provide a region id and distributor id',16,1)
    END
    else
    begin
        begin transaction

        update Region
        set DistributorID = @DistributorID
        where RegionID = @RegionID

        if @@ERROR<> 0
        begin
            raiserror('transfering distributor failed',16,1)
            rollback transaction
        end
        else
        begin
            update Distributor
            set wage = wage + 1
            where DistributorID = @DistributorID

            if @@ERROR<> 0
            begin
                raiserror('transfering distributor failed',16,1)
                rollback transaction
            end
            else
            begin
                commit transaction
            end
        end
    end
    return
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Looks like sqlserver from the raiserror call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the old distributor currently holding the region before you begin:

```
DECLARE @oldDist INT = (SELECT distributorid FROM region WHERE regionid = @regionid);
```

I'm not going to do all the work for you cause this is an academic exercise for your learning benefit, but that above, in the right place coupled with a slight copy paste change to a query you've already written will get you to where you need to be

Always always comment your work when learning

Use comments to form the high level algorithm - very few people think in code, they think in native language (eg English) and translate to code

Write the algorithm in English as comments then leave them in

```
--check values passed are valid and refer to existing region /distrib; throw a not found error if not

--get the old distributor id we are transferring from-will need this later 

--update to transfer to the new distrib

--update to increment new distrib wage

--update to decrement old distrib wage
```

That's what you should write first, then put code in below each comment to implement the comment

Other tips:

Use semicolons- omitting them is now deprecated

Don't get into a multiple nested if else if else he'll, its messy and unnecessary; you can do all this work at the base nest level because if you detect an error and raise it the procedure bombs out at that point (if your in a try block the severity needs to be greater than 10 to jump to the catch block)

Do not use RAISERROR - the docs state "new applications should use throw instead". Embarking on a path of using deprecated syntax is not good, discuss with your supervisor if this code skeleton came from them

Consider starting your transaction in a TRY, execute multiple statements and have a CATCH block that checks the @@TRANCOUNT and rolls the transaction back if it's greater than 0